# Rust `?` operator cannot be applied to type `&Option<T>`

Tags: rust

I'm just learning Rust, so I have some troubles with `?` and `&T1 -> &Option<T2>`.

I want to get reference and return inside reference, but into option.`fn (&self) -> Option<RSend>` but the problem is:  the `?` operator cannot be applied to type `&Option<RSend>`

The code is:

```
pub struct Bot {
    pub send_rule: Option<RSend>,
}  
pub struct RSend {
    pub d_low: Actor,
    pub d_high: Actor,
}
pub enum Actor { ... }

impl Bot {
    // COMPILES
    fn get_low_dest(&self) -> Option<&Actor> {
        match &self.send_rule {
            None => None,
            Some(rule) => Some(&rule.d_low),
        }
    }
    // DOES NOT COMPILES
    fn get_high_dest(&self) -> Option<&Actor> {
        let ss: &RSend = (&self.send_rule)?;
        return Some(&ss.d_high);
//Actually I would prefer to write something like this:
//      Some(&self.send_rule?.d_high)
    }  
}
```

As a result function `get_low_dest` compiles and function `get_high_dest` doesn't.

So how can I use `?` to refer inside another reference? And is there are some fundamental reasons why `?` does not implemented for `&Option<T>` (while deconstruction though `match` does)?

Comment: Existing answer explains that what you need to change to use `?` but there is another solution without  `?`:  `self.send_rule.as_ref().map(|ss| &ss.d_high)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Option::as_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) to convert `&Option<RSend>` to `Option<&RSend>`:

```rust
fn get_high_dest(&self) -> Option<&Actor> {
    let ss: &RSend = self.send_rule.as_ref()?;
    return Some(&ss.d_high);
}
```

Comment: They mentioned wanting something like this: `Some(&self.send_rule.as_ref()?.d_high)`

Comment: @PitaJ Well that also works.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your answer, just figured I'd note it, since they asked for it